# How to expand treeviewitem while performing drag and drop operation

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, treeview

When performing dragging over TreeView I want items to expand automatically when mouse cursor is over them for some time (eg. 2 seconds). What would be the approach to solve this problem?

Ideally I'd like to have a custom attached behavior implementation of this problem, something like for scrolling while dragging: http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2012/05/28/Attached-behavior-for-auto-scrolling-containers-while-doing-drag-amp-drop.aspx

In addition, I'd like to handle any other expandable (eg. Expander) or content-selectable (eg. TabControl) elements in a same manner, but I am not sure if all this can be handled generically (eg. with one attached behavior) or do I need to handle all of them separately?

Answer (score 0):

See my blog article entitled [Xaml: Adding Visibility Behaviors Using Blend to A DataGrid for WPF or Silverlight](http://omegacoder.com/?p=876) where it demonstrated a mouse over trigger. From that you can apply the behaviors you need using Blend to do the dirty work of adding the triggers.